# JavaScript redirect back to refer page

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I am trying to make a button OR direct redirect which redirect user to page where he come from.

For example: If someone access my website from bbc post and register. Upon register success page, There should be a button or redirect function which take user back to bbc post or whereever he comes from.

I tried following cookie method but not worked also read some posts on stackoverlow but still no luck!

```
function setCookie(name,val,days) {
// DATE OBJECT
var date = new Date();
// NUMBER OF MILLISECONDS IN A DAY
var milliseconds = 86400000;
// MULTIPLY, THEN ADD TO CURRENT TIME
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * milliseconds));
// SET EXPIRATION VARIABLE
var expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
// CONCATENATE TO CREATE COOKIE
document.cookie = name + '=' + val + expires + '; path=/';
}
window.onload = function(){
if(document.referrer != ''){
    // DESTROY ANY PREVIOUS DUPLICATE COOKIE
    setCookie('referrer','',-1);
    // CREATE COOKIE ON REGISTRATION PAGE
    setCookie('referrer',document.referrer,1);
    }
}
```

Can someone give any solution for this?

Comment: not tried `history.back()` yet. But will it work for refer url?

Comment: It can be used to send the browser back as if the user clicked the back button. I'm not entire sure if that's what you want from reading your question.

Comment: What if user click open in new tab? Will this work?

Comment: Any other solution please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following and it should be useable in used even if the tab is opened in a new window.

```
if(document.referrer != ''){
    // DESTROY ANY PREVIOUS DUPLICATE COOKIE
    setCookie('referrer','',-1);
    // CREATE COOKIE ON REGISTRATION PAGE
    setCookie('referrer',document.referrer,1);
    document.location.replace(document.referrer);
    //replaces current url with new one eg. the (current) url is removed from history
    //or
    document.location.href = document.referrer;
    //(current) url is in history/can use back button to go to previous page
}
```

Comment: Should i add it on current code above or this will work standalone?

Comment: Add which ever one you want (`href` or `replace`) to the current code because it won't work standalone without the `setCookie` function.

Comment: In your current code add the `replace` or `href` after `setCookie('referrer',document.referrer,1);` line

Comment: Yes i know, just wanted to make sure whole code wont break!